# Removing OT features, apparently can be done?

Tags: fontspec, luaotfload

Using TeXlive 2016 with LuaLaTeX on Ubuntu. Consider this MWE:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O} % A
% \setmainfont[RawFeature=+smcp]{Linux Libertine O} % B
% \setmainfont[Letters=SmallCaps]{Linux Libertine O} % C
\begin{document}
1: 36{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Lining}36}36\par
2: It was a {\addfontfeature{RawFeature=-smcp}dark} and stormy night.\par
\end{document}
```

With only A uncommented, line 1 shows OldStyle numbers by default, but Lining numbers where the feature is locally requested. Excellent!

With only B uncommented, line 2 shows small caps, except where the feature is locally removed. Excellent!

With only C uncommented, line 2 shows all small caps (the local removal does not work). Understandable, due to the different syntax.

I looked through the fontspec docs, and it is not clear whether this is undocumented experimental behavior, or not. A search for discussions on the subject (pipermail, etc.) suggests that, at least until recently, it was experimental.

I am particularly interested in the second case, where B is uncommented. My own code has a work-around that pre-processes the optional argument for `\setmainfont` and creates a hidden `basefont` with certain OT features stripped (if originally requested). If removal of features via negation of the 4-letter code is reliable, then I can get rid of my work-around.

A casual review of the code for luaotfload and fontspec leads me to belive that removal by negation is reliable. But I am not much of a coder. :(

Comment: Imho one should avoid to have contradicting settings like `+smcp;-smcp` in a font declaration. One can never be sure if the font really does what one expect. fontspec has improved in this respect and tries to remove doublettes etc. But users shouldn't make life for fontspec harder then necessary. So instead of `RawFeature=-smcp` I would try `Letters=ResetAll`.

Comment: I will try the Reset approach. Although there are many OT features, Letters and Numbers are the ones most crucial to the task in question. Still, since TeX is haunted by mathematicians, you'd think that the negative sign would be the first thing that comes to mind. :)

Comment: Well `-smcp` does work in your example, but I don't trust it to do the right thing all the time. I remember a discussion where `+liga;-liga;` had different results depending on the font. And if you use different keys (Letters and RawFeature) you even can't be sure about the order fontspec process and adds them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I have discovered what you wrote above, by trial and error. So, I have converted my code to the "fontspec approved" syntax for better reliability.